# jquery click event not working on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, mobile-devices, touchstart

I am trying to show a sidebar for mobile devices. When I click on an element I want to open that li tag with a sub menu. In the browser it's working fine, but on mobile devices it isn't working.

I also tried to use "**touchstart**" instead of click. The problem here is, when I touch the element and start scrolling, the sub menu will open. I only want to open it when I tapped / clicked on it.

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a class="filter-attribute"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i>head1</a>
      <ul class="child">
         <li class="filter-item"><input type="checkbox" name="attributeItems[]">sub1</li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".filter-attribute", function () {
$(this).next('.child').fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: You can use `touchstart` or `mousedown` for mobile devices

Comment: When I you mousedown, it's opening nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mousedown` for this. Check updated snippet below

```js
$(document).on("mousedown", ".filter-attribute", function () {
    $(this).siblings('.child').fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
    <a class="filter-attribute"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i>head1</a>
      <ul class="child">
         <li class="filter-item"><input type="checkbox" name="attributeItems[]">sub1</li>
      </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible that it isn't work for me because my content behind the sidebar is scrolling ?

Answer (score 0):

Try another way to make it, use touchstart event, it works on mobile devices:

```js
$(document).on("click touchstart", ".filter-attribute", function (e) {
    $(this).closest("li").find('.filter-item').fadeToggle("slow")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a class="filter-attribute"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i>head1</a>
      <ul class="child">
         <li class="filter-item"><input type="checkbox" name="attributeItems[]">sub1</li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: this doesn't open my sidebar

Comment: If I use my code above, with touchstart, it will open... but also when i'm scrolling, and that isn't looking nice